# Stack Over flow issue with practice problem

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

Good evening, currenlty I am stuck on this practice problem:
`How many ways can you make hundred coins using only nickels and dimes?`

Here's my code so far:

```
public class Recurrences {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("C(100) = " + C(100));
        System.out.println("F(47) = " + C(47));
        System.out.println("D(20) = " + C(20));
        System.out.println("U(19) = " + C(19));
    }

    private static long C(int n){
        if(n == 1) {
            return 1; 
        }
        if(n == 2) {
            return 1;
        }
       
        return C(n - 10) + C(n - 5);
        
    }
```

The error I recieve is a stack overflow error:

```
 at Recurrences.C(Recurrences.java:19)
        at Recurrences.C(Recurrences.java:19)
        at Recurrences.C(Recurrences.java:19)
        at Recurrences.C(Recurrences.java:19)
        at Recurrences.C(Recurrences.java:19)
        at Recurrences.C(Recurrences.java:19)
        at Recurrences.C(Recurrences.java:19)
```

How can I resolve my issue? What exit condition can I use?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.  Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger?  Consider what happens if you do, say, `C(3)`.  On the first recursion, you'll invoke `C(-7)` ... then what happens?

Comment: My goal is to find how many can you make 100 coins using two coins, dimes, and nickels, using the equation: C(n - 10) + C(n - 5), since C(N) is the number of ways we can have 100 coins through dimes and nickels.

Comment: Step through the code using `C(13)` as a starting point.

Comment: it shows me `n = 13`

Comment: And then it keeps going forever.... `n=-17`, `n=-27`, etc. no?

Comment: `n` keeps changing when I began debugging my code. Yes.

Comment: Would I need to use a exit condition to prevent the loop from going forever?

Comment: That's how recursion works -- you must have an exit condition that always occurs at some point in order to prevent infinite recursion ... and StackOverflow.

Comment: What exit condition would be best suited for what am I trying to do?

Comment: Maybe something to do with negative numbers?